# Heroku: removed file in Public folder is still there in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I added a sitemap.xml file to the Public folder of a Rails application hosted on Heroku. Since then, I removed it and `git push heroku master` the new version without the file.

However, the file is still there. How can I do to remove it in production?

I tried `rake assets:clean` and `rake assets:precompile` without success. I also used the Heroku Repo plugin to `heroku repo:purge_cache` and `heroku repo:reset` but the file is still there!

Thanks.

Comment: Seems odd. Can you try in incognito to make sure it's not cached or something like that?

Comment: Also, are you sure `git add . && git commit -m "something" && git push` succeeded prior to `git push heroku master` ?

Comment: Damn @stevec, that was it! I feel so dumb... thanks!